# How to make a button event handler Method in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am new to C# and I am making a small tic-tac-toe game using WPF. However, I would like to make my code compact and would like to create a method which will take button click event as argument and modify the button. For the time being, this is what I am trying to do:

```
Button.IsEnabled = false;
Button.Content = "X";
```

I want to make a event which will do this job when called inside a button click event and hence I will not need to copy this code for every button.

Comment: And what is stopping you from using the same event for all your buttons?

Comment: Well, I want to make a method since there will be more codes beside the two lines I provided. I don't want to copy the same codes over and over for all the buttons, instead I would like to create a method which will initiate the code when called inside a button.

Comment: You don't need to copy anything other than have the XAML with the same event for all your buttons like ShayD answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN the xaml, add the event handler to the button:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" />
```

(add the same handler to all buttons)
in the code behind, cast the sender to a button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.IsEnabled = false;
            button.Content = "X";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach the event handler and use the `sender`:

```
Button.Click += this.Button_Click;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;

    if (button != null)
    {
        button.IsEnabled = false;
        button.Content = X;
     }
}
```